# Can I build easily a static binary to be used inside fakeroot and how?

Tags: linker, static-linking

fakeroot seems to build some  libfakeroot.a (but inside  a .lib directory).
But I am not sure, that the static linker can indeed replace/rename symbols  as the dynamic linker can.

Answer (score 2):

Fakeroot uses the dynamic linker in order to do its magic (specifically, LD_PRELOAD). Unfortunately, the dynamic linker is not involved in loading statically linked binaries (which is how the dynamic linker itself is invoked: /lib/ld-linux.so.2 is statically compiled).

As answered above, your only option, as far as I'm aware, is to use [fakeroot-ng](http://fakeroot-ng.lingnu.com), which uses a completely different mechanism to inject into the process, and is, thus, able to work on statically linked libraries without a problem.

In fact, statically linked libraries was part of the reason I set out to write fakeroot-ng in the first place. At the time, there was no way to tell ldconfig to run on a subtree, and ldconfig is statically linked.

Shachar

Answer (score 1):

seems the solution is to use  fakeroot-ng, which works for statically linked binaries.